# A form with 3 submits; how to keep data for final submit?

Tags: php, forms

I  have created a PHP form which requires the user to select a postcode from a list of postcode values.

The user presses submit two times:
- once to go to address select menu which will display a select drop-down with values
- second presses "ok" button to select the address corresponding to his postcode value

I need to keep the value of the selected postcode value for when the form gets submitted. I have tried setting up the postcode drop-down value chosen in a SESSION... but it gets lots when user presses form submit.

How can I keep all the form values even after refreshing the page when the user presses one of the submits?

Comment: Be sure to **always** start the session using `session_start()` before trying to access/create `$_SESSION` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"How can I keep all the form values even after refreshing the page when the user presses one of the submits?"*

Reading your question I didn't understand if each of the form submits actually gets submitted to the server, but I'm going to assume so. I'm also assuming you're trying to use PHP sessions to accomplish this.

When the user submits the form, save the values server-side in a PHP session

```
//Start the session
session_start();
//Save the values
$_SESSION["foo"] = $_POST["bar"];
...
```

If, after choosing the address, the user gets redirected to the initial form and you want to populate that:

```php
//Start the session
<?php
   session_start();
?>
```

```
<!-- Populate HTML form based on previously submitted values -->
<input type="text" name="foo" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["foo"] ?>" />
...
```

After the final submit you should have all the submitted values saved in the `$_SESSION` array. Don't forget to always `session_start()` before trying to handle anything session related.

Comment: I call session_start on the first line of a header.php file, which is included in the forms file. I am not sure how I have to use session_start.. so it should always be declared before any headers are sent, but if I include in header.php it will always be called on page refresh (in theory)? I will try your suggestion tomorrow, thank you.

Comment: As long as you call `session_start()` **before** you get or set data from the `$_SESSION` array you should be good. If your header file is included in every page you want to get/set `$_SESSION` data then it should work.

Comment: Solved, the issue was that I was doing everything correct except setting the session_start() correctly. As this form is part of a Wordpress template, I have now called correctly the session start as:// enable sessions in wordpress 
function cp_admin_init()
{
    if (!session_id())
    {
        session_start();
    }
}

add_action('init', 'cp_admin_init'); in the functions.php file and it now works correctly. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is I don't think you can track form data across multiple forms.

I haven't seen your project and so might not fully understand the requirements, but I would suggest you consider using AJAX.  Check out the [jQuery post() manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), it's really simple actually.  This has the advantage of allowing you to update the page once your first form has been completed.

EDIT:  Sorry I meant you can't access multiple form data in a single $_POST.  Of course you could store it in $_SESSION (remember to start your session properly).

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I cannot use this approach as I am using a webservice to get all form validation errors.